# Eclipse kepler git synchronize not working

Tags: git, synchronization, eclipse-kepler

I am using Eclipse kepler version where git synchronize is not working, I was not able to see conflicts files, updated files for a particular repository. But this was working for indigo version.

[image]

In the above images I am getting empty git repository, but I have git repository in my workspace. Do not how to solve this.

I have updated egit version with below url, but it doesn't fix the issue

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.2

Comment: Do not reuse workspaces when upgrading eclipse.  Create new ones.

Answer (score 0):

EGit 2.2 seems ancient: check if updating to a [more recent EGit (3.6.2)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F) wouldn't fix the issue.

Check also (first) if the "[Repository Configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Repository_Configuration)" of your current repo is configured in EGit:

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/e/e2/RepoMgrRemoteConfig.png]